# concat select not use in where clause (mysql)

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I want to make filtering a table, but in the table there is a `user_id` column and I want to filter on its real table (I mean `users.username`).

My code:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `id`, `user_id`, `payment_type`, 
 `is_paid`, `is_invoiced`, `invoice_number`, `created_at`, `ip`,
 `data`, `coupon_code`, `payment_total`, 
 (select CONCAT(users.name,' ',users.surname) from users where users.id = orders.user_id) as fullname
FROM orders
WHERE (`fullname` LIKE '%M%' OR `payment_type` LIKE '%M%') ORDER BY `is_invoiced` asc
```

When I excecuted it, there is an error like this: `Unknown column 'fullname' in 'where clause'`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: By the way why do use LIKE '%M%' for fullname when it looks like there is only one result for user's name always because of users.id? And you use orders.user_id when orders table is used outside the subquery? Would you mind showing actual data from you tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `CONCAT` in `WHERE` clause like:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `id`, `user_id`, `payment_type`, 
`is_paid`, `is_invoiced`, `invoice_number`, `created_at`, `ip`,
`data`, `coupon_code`, `payment_total`, 
(select CONCAT(users.name,' ',users.surname) from users
WHERE CONCAT(users.name,' ',users.surname) LIKE '%M%'
and users.id = orders.user_id) as fullname
FROM orders
WHERE `payment_type` LIKE '%M%' ORDER BY `is_invoiced` asc
```

Comment: you're welcome @MuhammetArslan. You can accept the answer that really works for you by the way. GOD bless and Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can only use column aliases in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.

From MySQL documentation:

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet be determined

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, user_id, payment_type, is_paid, 
is_invoiced, invoice_number, created_at, ip, data, coupon_code,
payment_total, (select CONCAT(users.name,' ',users.surname) 
from users where users.id = orders.user_id) as fullname 
FROM orders HAVING (fullname LIKE '%M%' OR payment_type LIKE '%M%') 
ORDER BY is_invoiced asc;
```